# Blank Page on localhost when i run the sln file in an existing project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an sln file from an existing project. When i run the sln in my visual studio, it opens my browser with URL  `localhost:5119`  however, the page is empty. There are no errors in my console.

What could be the issue ?

**PS:: Beginner in C#**

PS: IIS is running on port 80.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its hard to predict you anything you should share more details like your `code`, `index file` or application `route`

Comment: When you say "console" do you mean the browser's javascript console? Are there any clues in the browser network trace? What content do you expect to see?

Comment: if your project is MVC, check `RouteConfig.cs` in `App_Start` folder, here you can find out which controller will be startup object. If it's a WebForm project, usually Default.aspx is a startup page. although there is some approaches like checking `Web.Config` file to find `<defaultDocument>` which shows start up page.